# Kotlin DataBinding pass static function into layout xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

In Java, i can easily pass static function to layout xml using:

```
public static String formatUnixTime(long timeInSeconds, String pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US);
    String value = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(timeInSeconds * 1000));

    return value;
}
```

in xml:

```
android:text='@{Utils.formatUnixTime(model.start_time, "hh:mm:ss")}'
```

But i tried in Kotlin with `companion` but no luck. It said

```
error: cannot find symbol
import my.package.name.HistoryItemBindingImpl;
                      ^
  symbol:   class HistoryItemBindingImpl
  location: package my.package.name
```

This is what i tried in kotlin

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        fun formatUnixTime(timeInSeconds : Long, pattern: String) : String {
            val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)
            val value = simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeInSeconds * 1000))

            return value
        }
    }
```

And in xml

```
android:text='@{Utils.Companion.formatUnixTime(model.start_time, "hh:mm:ss")}'
```

Really hope someone can help. Thanks!

**Update**
With @Max Aves help. I fixed my code and below code will work. Maybe it will help someone.

```
class Utils {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun formatUnixTime(timeInSeconds : Long, pattern: String) : String {
            val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)
            val value = simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeInSeconds * 1000))

            return value
        }
```

And you can use this in xml

```
android:text='@{Utils.formatUnixTime(model.start_time, "hh:mm:ss")}'
```

Comment: i have moved this fun in java it worked. But in Kotlin it is not working.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried adding `@JvmStatic` annotation? It should help!

From official [source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html):

> Specifies that an additional static method needs to be generated from
>   this element if it's a function. If this element is a property,
>   additional static getter/setter methods should be generated.

Comment: `@JvmStatic` really help me. I've tried to use `object` instead of `class` before but no luck. Thanks alot. Have a nice day.

Comment: u2, enjoy  coding

Comment: After one year your answer still help ! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Utilities are generally created as Kotlin File. Because Kotlin files methods are global. Which you can use from anywhere without making it `@JvmStatic`.

**BindingAdapterDefault.kt**

```
fun formatUnixTime(timeInSeconds: Long, pattern: String): String {
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)
    return simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeInSeconds * 1000))
}
```

That will work for you same, **NO** class, brackets, companion, object etc...

**From XML**

```
<import type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.ui2.BindingAdapterDefaultKt"/>

android:text="@{BindingAdapterDefaultKt.formatUnixTime(1540966388,`hh:mm:ss`)}"
```

#### That's all you need.

I want add more info about this. You can directly call this method from Java and Kotlin too.

**From Java class**

```
import static com.package.BindingAdapterDefaultKt.formatUnixTime;
formatUnixTime(454545, "hh:mm:ss");
```

**From Kotlin class**

```
import com.package.formatUnixTime
formatUnixTime(454545, "hh:mm:ss");
```

#### Suggestion

I prefer creating [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) which was introduced with Data Binding, and is very powerful thing. It gives me more flexibility across the app.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:formatSeconds="@{1540966388}"
    app:pattern="@{`hh:mm:ss`}"
    />
```

**BindingAdapterDefault.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["formatSeconds", "pattern"])
fun secondsToDateText(textView: TextView, timeInSeconds: Long, pattern: String) {
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)
    textView.text = simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeInSeconds * 1000))
}
```

Comment: I also tried `BindingAdapter` before in Java. But really don't know how to do it in Kotlin because i tried somethings like your last codes, but it throw not-detailed error. So I changed to use above way. Thanks for very detailed information. And do I need to pass `@JvmStatic` before `@BindingAdapter(value = ["formatSeconds", "pattern"])`? Thanks.

Comment: As I said kotlin file functions are global, so you don't need to specify `@JvmStatic`, - Actually you can't also, try it :)

Comment: I have posted related complete code here. So no need to worry about anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `@JvmStatic`, you can use `object` instead of `class`:

```
object Utils {

    fun formatUnixTime(timeInSeconds : Long, pattern: String) : String {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.US)
        val value = simpleDateFormat.format(Date(timeInSeconds * 1000))
        return value
    }
}
```

From `xml` import the `Utils` singleton class and then:

```
android:text='@{Utils.INSTANCE.formatUnixTime(model.start_time, "hh:mm:ss")}'
```