# Data Binding - Cannot call function from a layout file

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding

I'm trying to call a function from my Data Binding layout, but I'm always receiving some error. I'm trying to set the text on my textView using MyUtilClass's function which I have created. here's my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.example.testapp.User"/>
        <import type="com.example.testapp.MyUtilClass"/>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="User" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{MyUtilClass.Companion.changeText(user.firstName)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

MyUtilClass

```
class MyUtilClass {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun changeText(text: String): String {
            return text
        }
    }

}
```

User

```
data class User(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int,
    val loggedIn: Boolean
)
```

MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val myUser = User("John", "Doe", 25, true)

        binding.user = myUser
    }

}
```

Error:

> C:\Users\Stefan\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApp\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\testapp\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:9:
> error: cannot find symbol import
> com.example.testapp.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
> ^   symbol:   class ActivityMainBindingImpl   location: package
> com.example.testapp.databinding
>
> cannot find method changeText(java.lang.String) in class
> com.example.testapp.MyUtilClass.Companion Open File

Comment: try removing companion from layout xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the change I made, and it worked. I basically removed class keyword and added object instead.

```
object MyUtilClass {

    @JvmStatic
    fun changeText(text: String): String {
        return text
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding JvmStatic to the changeText() method in MyUtilClass automatically makes it static.
Therefore, you can access it like this in your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.example.testapp.User"/>
        <import type="com.example.testapp.MyUtilClass"/>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="User" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{MyUtilClass.changeText(user.firstName)}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

You can check this link to find out more:
[Kotlin DataBinding pass static function into layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058509/kotlin-databinding-pass-static-function-into-layout-xml)